# How to limit the following loop so it only displays the first matched element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm displaying the div based on the value of the properties of a JavaScript object. I want to display the FIRST thumbnail that the object has:

```
// HTML
<div v-for="value in object" v-if="valueIsValid(value)">

// JS
if (value instanceof Array) { // check if it's an array
  const propertyIsThumbnail = _.find(value, 'thumbnail')
  if (propertyIsThumbnail) { // get the values only if their key is 'thumbnail'
    return value.length > 0 // return if the thumbnail is not empty
  }
} else {
  return true // return everything else that's not an array.
```

It works with this kind of objects:

```
{
  "livingroom": [],
  "bedroom": [],
  "study": [
    {
      "name": "s0",
      "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sig@staging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/thumb_螢幕快照 2016-03-29 下午2.12.32.png",
      "web": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sigstaging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/201603292.12.32.png"
    }
  ],
```

But with these:

```
{
  "livingroom": [],
  "bedroom": [
    {
      "name": "s0",
      "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sig@staging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/thumb_螢幕快照 2016-03-29 下午2.12.32.png",
      "web": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sigstaging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/201603292.12.32.png"
    }
  ],
  "study": [
    {
      "name": "s0",
      "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sig@staging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/thumb_螢幕快照 2016-03-29 下午2.12.32.png",
      "web": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sigstaging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/201603292.12.32.png"
    }
  ],
```

It makes the div display more than one time, because there are more than one category that isn't empty. And what I want is to display ONLY the first category that it isn't empty (the first thumbnail).

How to accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

This is the beginning of the loop:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
  <div
    v-for="object in className | orderOrFilterBy searchProp"
    class="list-item col-md-12 clearfix"
  >
    <div
      v-if="keyIsVisible($key) && valueIsValid(value)"
      v-for="value in object"
      :class="[setColumnsByKey($key), setColumnAlignment($key)]"
    >
```

Comment: The same key ("thumbnail") appears twice..?

Comment: @NicklasWinger Yes, each category has that key.

Comment: Just break the loop once you've found the first one.
Optionally, set the first item to a property that you use to display in your markup.

Comment: could you show us the full length of the code starting from the beginning of the loop?

Comment: @Ali I posted the beginning of the loop. The first loop loops through the objects and the second nested one through the value of those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how to achieve what you want. I use a global variable `thumbnailFound` to determine if thumbnail was found, but in your case you might want to use something more robust. Let me know if it worked!

```
    // HTML
    <div v-for="property in object" v-if="valueIsValid(property)">

    // JS
    var thumbnailFound;

    function valueIsValid (property) {

        if (!Array.isArray(property)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (thumbnailFound) {
            return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < property.length; i++ ) {
            let thumbnail = property[i].thumbnail;

            if (thumbnail && thumbnail.length) {
                thumbnailFound = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        return !!(thumbnailFound);

    };
```